# Rails 5 - Multiple objects in one form (Non nested)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 5 I am trying to create multiple records via one form and am having difficulty finding an answer that is not related to nested forms.

I have a Tutor model which has many availabilities.

```
class Tutor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :availabilities, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Availabilities belong to Tutor

```
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tutor, optional: true
end
```

An availability simply has day, from and to attributes.

```
  create_table "availabilities", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer  "day"
   t.integer  "tutor_id"
   t.time     "from"
   t.time     "to"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.index ["tutor_id"], name: "index_availabilities_on_tutor_id", 
   using: :btree
  end
```

I understand that I can use nested forms to create multiple availabilities when initially creating the tutor.

However what I am trying to do is to create multiple availabilities when the tutor goes to the availability/new page (when the tutor has already created).

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at this, very good tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/better-nested-attributes-in-rails-with-the-cocoon-gem/